# MySQL query returns more rows than intended, how do i only return the highest value of one column from each group?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query needs to return all rows with the highest value of 'revision' column out of each group of 'sheet_ID' column.  It works fine when i do not do the OR statement but i need to be able to use them.  The input field is for 'Item Numbers' and the or statement needs to pull that number from a possible of 10 columns where it can be.

Here is my Query statement:

```
SELECT item_no, item_no1, item_no2, item_no3, item_no4, item_no5, item_no6,
       item_no7, item_no8, item_no9, style, vendor_code, pgc, buyer, brand,
       product_name, sheet_ID, revision, id
FROM product_sheets
WHERE item_no LIKE '$value' or item_no1 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no2 LIKE '$value' or item_no3 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no4 LIKE '$value' or item_no5 LIKE '$value' or 
      item_no6 LIKE '$value' or item_no7 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no8 LIKE '$value' or item_no9 LIKE '$value' AND
      revision IN (SELECT MAX(revision)
                   FROM product_sheets
                   GROUP BY sheet_ID
                  );
```

Comment: See normalization. Any time you have enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing. Any other suggestion is frankly ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use brackets around th `or` conditions, without them only the last condition `item_no9 LIKE '$value'` is related with an AND operator to the `IN` condition.

```
WHERE (item_no LIKE '$value' or item_no1 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no2 LIKE '$value' or item_no3 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no4 LIKE '$value' or item_no5 LIKE '$value' or 
      item_no6 LIKE '$value' or item_no7 LIKE '$value' or
      item_no8 LIKE '$value' or item_no9 LIKE '$value'
      )
```

In addition change the `IN` condition to the following.
You don't want a revision that is not the max revision of of its sheet_ID to match with a max revision of another sheet_ID.

```
      AND (sheet_ID,revision) IN (SELECT sheet_ID,MAX(revision)
                                  FROM product_sheets
                                  GROUP BY sheet_ID
                                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 revision IN (SELECT MAX(revision)
               FROM product_sheets
               GROUP BY sheet_ID
              );
```

You want a correlated subquery.  In your case, you can write it as:

```
 revision = (SELECT MAX(ps2.revision)
              FROM product_sheets ps2
              WHERE ps2.sheet_ID = product_sheets.sheet_ID
             );
```

However, I would strongly advise you to use a table alias in the outer query.

You also need to fix the parentheses in the `where`:

```
WHERE (item_no LIKE '$value' or item_no1 LIKE '$value' or
       item_no2 LIKE '$value' or item_no3 LIKE '$value' or
       item_no4 LIKE '$value' or item_no5 LIKE '$value' or 
       item_no6 LIKE '$value' or item_no7 LIKE '$value' or
       item_no8 LIKE '$value' or item_no9 LIKE '$value'
      ) AND
      revision = (SELECT MAX(ps2.revision)
                  FROM product_sheets ps2
                  WHERE ps2.sheet_ID = product_sheets.sheet_ID
                 );
```

If `$value` doesn't use wildcards, this is much more simply written as:

```
where '$value' in (item_no, item_no1, item_no2, . . .) and
      revision = (SELECT MAX(ps2.revision)
                  FROM product_sheets ps2
                  WHERE ps2.sheet_ID = product_sheets.sheet_ID
                 );
```

And, in addition to the comment about normalization (which is strongly suggested), you also need to learn about using query parameters to pass in values to a query.